# C++ templates and pointers to incomplete types

Tags: c++, templates

How does the compiler know how `obj` looks like? It is not included in `form.h`, but it works anyway.

### form.h

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

template <class T>
class Form
{
public:
    Form(T* obj) {}
};

#endif // FORM_H
```

### mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    form = new Form<MainWindow>(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: I've answered as best I can, but this question is kind of unclear without a better description of which part of "what `obj` looks like" you're interested in. There are several interesting facets involved in this code and we don't know which ones you care about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler knows what `obj` looks like because, as a `T*`, `obj` is a pointer and the compiler knows intimately what *all* pointers look like.

It doesn't need to know what `T` looks like, to deal with a `T*`.

*If* you were to dereference that pointer and use the `T` it points to, inside the class definition, then yes the definition of `T` would have to be available. But this is guaranteed to be true anyway because any code that instantiates `Form<T>` must already know, at the very least, that the chosen `T` is a class. Beyond that all the usual rules about forward-declarations apply.